# Automatic Facebook access token generation using my account on server?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The goal: Using **my** account I would like a server to periodically check the feed of a closed group which I'm a member of.

The problem: To do that I need an access token which I can generate manually but it expires.

What I would like to be able to do: Automatically generate access tokens for my account from the server in some way without manual interaction.

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible and it is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WizKid commented, it´s not possible to generate Access Tokens on the server. The whole concept of short time Tokens would be useless if that would be possible. You can only extend your User Token to 60 days, read the docs for information about that:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0#getlonglivedsession